# Wrong Interface Orientation Reported in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have been using the following to detect the current interface orientation in iOS 14/15:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.windowScene!.interfaceOrientation
```

Now in iOS 16 Beta (1 and 2), it is reporting incorrectly. Landscape is being reported as Portrait Upsidedown.

Comment: What is the question? If there's a bug in the beta, you should report it via Feedback Assistant

Comment: I am trying to see if there is a way around it.

Comment: Probably the only way around it is to downgrade from the beta or wait for the next beta version to drop.  In the meantime, this kind of thing is better posted on the apple developer forums where actual Apple engineers can respond directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
            self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
            self.navigationController?.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
            windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscape)) { error in
                print(error)
                print(windowScene?.effectiveGeometry ?? "")
            }
        }
        
    } else {
        appDelegate.myOrientation = .landscape
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
```

Apple deprecated UIDevice orientation related api's in iOS_16 instead use **requestGeometryUpdate** method which requests an update to the window scenes geometry.

For detailed information kindly check the following apple developer documentation.
[requestGeometryUpdate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3975944-requestgeometryupdate/)

If you still not able to rotate the device successfully, kindly check the below link for possible root cause and the solution.

[UISceneErrorDomain Code=101 issue and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73804654/6643110)

Comment: not working in ipad

Answer (score 0):

I managed to deal with it in this way:

```objectivec
if (@available(iOS 16, *)) {
    float windowWidth = gameScene.view.window.frame.size.width;
    float windowHeight = gameScene.view.window.frame.size.height;
    
    if (windowWidth > windowHeight) {
        orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    } else {
        orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
} else {
    orientation = gameScene.view.window.windowScene.interfaceOrientation;
}
```